# How to get consistent result while dealing with float in php

Tags: php, floating-point

Here is the code:

```
$nums = ['3','3','5.26','3','9.11','9.11','9.11','9.11','9.11','9.11','9.11','9.11','9.11','1.25','1.25','1.25'];
$total = 0;
$accuracy = 0.00001;
foreach($nums as $num) {
    $total += floatval($num);
}

var_dump($total);                           //float(100)
var_dump($total == 100);                    //bool(false)
var_dump(abs($total - 100));                //float(1.4210854715202E-14)
var_dump(abs($total - 100) < $accuracy);    //bool(false)

$nums = ['3','3','5.23','3','13.67','13.67','13.67','13.67','13.67','13.67','1.25','1.25','1.25'];
$total = 0;
foreach($nums as $num) {
    $total += floatval($num);
}

var_dump($total);                           //float(100)
var_dump($total == 100);                    //bool(false)
var_dump(abs($total - 100));                //float(0)
var_dump(abs($total - 100) < $accuracy);    //bool(true)
```

As you can see above, there are 2 different sets of number. Both have sum of 100. But when dealing with float, the result can be inconsistent.

This is my use case:

Exam can have many questions, each questions can have different score, but exam can only active when sum of scores is exactly 100.

One exam can be active, the other cannot. And I have a LOT of number set and there are 50:50 chance of PHP view them as "exactly 100". What is the best way to consistently getting a sum of 100 using float?

Comment: Round to an acceptable number of decimal places. If only 2 are relevant, you can use `round($num * 100) / 100`, if 3 are relevant use `round($num * 1000) / 1000` and so on. You can use the `pow` function to set something similar up too: `round($num * pow(10,$dp)) / pow(10,$dp)`

Comment: This does not reproduce when I take the first code, add some `echo` statements to show the values, and run it. For example, with `$b = abs($total - 100) < $accuracy;
echo "$b <br>";`, the output is “1”, for true, where the question indicates it would be false. Edit the question to provide a [mre], including complete code that can be executed without change or addition to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil edited the code with var_dump. In my machine, the first set result in false. I don't know how it was true on yours but the fact that $total - 100 was not 0 in the first set means it has some remainders.

Comment: I pasted your code inside the `<?php` and `?>` markers of [this online PHP compiler](https://www.w3schools.com/php/phptryit.asp?filename=tryphp_compiler) and clicked Run, and it showed the output “float(100) bool(false) float(1.4210854715202E-14) bool(true)”.